# Can I change the HUD key (Alt)?

Tags: unity, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I am using the combination Alt+Shift to change the keyboard language (Eng -> Greek and Greek -> Eng).
Since the introduction of HUD, each time I press the keys Alt+Shift the HUD (search) bar also appears.
Is there any way to change the activation key for HUD?